# Shim config to load angular js and dependencies

Tags: magento-2.1, requirejs, angularjs

I have an angular js app that I want to integrate into Magento 2 so I created require-js config like below

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            angular: 'Test_Custom/js/angular',
            angularroute: 'Test_Custom/js/angular-route',
            angularanimate : 'Test_Custom/js/angular-animate',
            app : 'Test_Custom/js/app',
            minecontroller : 'Test_Custom/js/mine-controller',
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularroute':{
            deps:['angular']
        },
        'angularanimate':{
            deps:['angular']
        },
        'app': {
            deps: ['angular','angularroute']
        },
        'minecontroller': {
            deps: ['angular','app']
        }
    }
};
```

and added this script in a template file

```
<script>
  require(['jquery' , 'jquery/ui','app','minecontroller'], function () {
   });
</script>
```

JS files are getting loaded as per dependencies but, I am getting error -

Failed to instantiate module `Mine` due to Module 'Mine' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Is there anything I have to change in the shim config?